# Solve $(n+1)^k-1=n!$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial, binomial-theorem

Solve $(n+1)^k-1=n!$ in positive integers.

So far, I can see that $n! = -1$ (mod $n+1$), which is true for all $n+1$ prime. Also, $(1,1), (2,1), (4,2)$ are solutions. They seem like special cases, and I might need to prove something about mod $5$, since I do not see solutions above that. However, I cannot continue.

Comment: There are three small solutions

Comment: Thanks, editing the post

Comment: $n+1$ *must* be prime.

Comment: May I know why is that so?

Comment: $n+1$ must be prime since $n! \equiv -1 \pmod{n + 1}$. See [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

Comment: Oh, I thought the theorem goes in one direction only...

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? I looked like a textbook exercise at first, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: It is from a tuition exercise lol

Comment: @BarryCipra. This would be a very nice problem replacing $n$ by $x$

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that for any $k \geq 1$, there are two solutions.